Can NASM be forced to generate mov with offset of 0?
My question
I have tried using NASM's strict keyword and -O0 to inhibit it from turning mov dword [rdi+0], 0xab into mov dword [rdi], 0xab, but haven't been successful. My hunch is that the +0 gets preprocessed, or that it is such a simple "optimization" that it can't be disabled, but I don't know NASM well enough to be certain, so I'm looking for confirmation, and other ideas.
Reproducing
foo.s:
foo:
    mov dword [rdi+0], 0xab
    mov dword [rdi+4], 0xcd
    ret

Running nasm -f elf64 foo.s and then xxd foo.o outputs this line:
00000180: c707 ab00 0000 c747 04cd 0000 00c3 0000  .......G........

So the first mov is turned into c707 ab00 0000, and the second into c747 04cd 0000 00. Notice how the second mov isn't the same, taking an extra 04 offset byte.
Why the hell do you want this
So I know this sounds like an XY problem, but I'm writing my first compiler for my own programming language. I am trying to keep the compiler as small and simple as possible, happily trading some of the output's performance away. In order to make sure my compiler's output is correct, I am comparing the .so it outputs to the one that NASM+ld together outputs, which means that every one of my tests has a .s NASM file. This frees me from having to worry about whether my compiler's output is correct, but it does mean my compiler needs to output the exact same bytes as NASM+ld for my tests.
Someone suggested using objcopy to edit text section bytes, but simply search-and-replacing c707 with c747 00 of course won't do, since those bytes might be say a regular constant in the code. I could have my tests.sh do something like first get the offsets of all of the instructions' first bytes, and then use that to limit the search-and-replace, but I'm not sure yet whether I'd use objcopy or objdump to somehow get these offsets.
For now I just put this if-statement in my compiler for the special case of offset 0. I am aware that compilers for programming languages typically can't hardcode stuff like this, but with the way I designed my programming language it works just fine:
for (size_t i = 0; i < moved_value_count; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        // moving value (0xab) to index 0:
        // c707 ab00 0000
    } else {
        // moving value (0xcd) to index 1, 2, etc:
        // c747 04cd 0000 00
    }
}


Put a byte or dword keyword into the brackets like mov dword [byte rdi+0], 0xab

As a side note, the typical solution is to emit an assembly file yourself not an object file; but no reason you have to do that.

@ecm: Any idea why NASM doesn't even allow [strict byte rdi + 0] or [strict byte 0 + rdi] for that?  The strict keyword is used in other cases where you want to override the machine-code choices.

@Joshua It's the guy who wants to know the addresses of all symbols at compile time, so I guess that would be hard.

@PeterCordes No, unfortunately I do not know.

@fuz: Sound's hard. Use labels.

@Joshua I guess I could emit assembly/some custom IR with labels, but I want it to generate the .so from scratch without any outside assembler (as a learning experience mostly), so I'd have to resolve the labels to addresses at some point anyway.


If you want a particular offset size, indicate the regular data size prefixes.
That means
mov dWord [byte RDI], 0xAB

which is shorthand for
mov dWord [byte RDI + 0], 0xAB

becomes 7-byte opcode + modrm + disp8 + imm32
C7 47 00 AB 00 00 00

Unlike other cases where strict is used to force certain encodings in NASM, strict byte or strict dword isn't accepted in this context.

If you want a disp32=0, you could also force the register to be an index instead of base, although that will additionally require a SIB byte, making the instruction 11 bytes instead of the 10 you'd get from mov dword [dword rdi + 0], constant.
One way to do that is NASM’s split EA (effective address) notation:
mov dWord [0, RDI], 0xAB

becomes 11 bytes:
C7 04 3D 00 00 00 00 AB 00 00 00

For the sake of completeness, the full syntax reads
[base_register + displacement_constant,   scale_register * index_register]

Another way to force a register to be an index instead of a shorter encoding where it might be a base is the nosplit keyword.  mov dword [nosplit rdi*1 + 0], 0xab

The machine code you're showing doesn't have the 0x000000ab immediate.  The whole instruction is 11 bytes, c7 04 3d 00 00 00 00 ab 00 00 00        mov    DWORD PTR [rdi*1+0x0],0xab, using RDI as an index.  Having a disp32=0 is possible without a SIB byte with mov dword [dword rdi+0], 0xab as @ecm commented, so this wastes more space.

Also, the OP probably only wants disp8=0, a zero byte, not a disp32.  Anyway, I didn't know this syntax variant existed in NASM, so that's interesting, but the current version of your answer presents it very poorly, not directly explaining what you're really getting except in the "full syntax" part, and omitting the byte or dword overrides that let you get the shortest possible instructions that still have a disp8=0 or disp32=0.

You missed the point of my comment.  The 7 bytes you show in the first half of your answer is actually just the first 7 of an 11-byte instruction, the same one you're showing in the bottom half.  You cut it off after the disp32, before the imm32, which is why I downvoted.  When there's no base register (only an index or no index), there's always a disp32 not a disp8, and since you force RDI to be an index there's a SIB byte.  The 7-byte instruction is c7 47 00 ab 00 00 00 from NASM mov dword [byte rdi+0], 0xab

@Peter I’m sorry my explanations are, quote, poor. I do not actually really know how exactly this works.

Ok, I fixed your answer to show the efficient way first, to just request a disp8=0 or disp32=0.  And added information about why it wastes bytes to force RDI to be an index as a way to get a disp32.
